# mvvmlight wpf how to raise frame source property wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

(See Solution below)

Struggling learning MVVMLight and WPF.  Happy to get page navigation with a frame with 3 buttons and also get the CanExecute RelayCommand functionality working for the buttons.

However, when I change pages with the Back and Forward button from the frame, the frame navigation buttons seem to not raise the propertychanged for the Frame Source Property FrameURI in the viewmodel.  In the RelayCommand execute I'm looking at the FrameURI property to determine button command can execute.  I'm thinking that I need to raisepropertychange of FrameURI property in the viewmodel after a Frame FWD or BACK button press.  It looks like I can do that in a Navigated or LoadCompleted EVENT from the [NavigationService Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).  Is this the best way to go about this?  Maybe there's an easier way?

PROPER BEHAVIOR HERE:

[image: CANEXECUTE WORKS WELL HERE!]

NOT WORKING CORRECTLY HERE when the frame BACK button is pressed.  The page changes (good), but the button Middle canexecute didn't update correctly.  See property and relay commands further below.

[image: CanExecute not working]

MVVMINPCPROPERTY snippet

```
    public const string FrameUriPropertyName = "FrameUri";

    private Uri _frameUri;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the FrameUri property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public Uri FrameUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _frameUri;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(FrameUriPropertyName, ref _frameUri, value);
        }
    }
```

XAML for Frame

```
    <Frame  x:Name="MainFrameDS"  Source="{Binding FrameUri}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="211" Margin="109,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258"/>
```

RelayCommand example

```
    private RelayCommand _changeToLastPage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ChangeToLastPage.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand ChangeToLastPage
    {
        get
        {
            return _changeToLastPage
                ?? (_changeToLastPage = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    FrameUri = ViewModelLocator.LastPageUri;                       
                },
            () => FrameUri != ViewModelLocator.LastPageUri));                
        }
    }
```

I have the [source code on github](https://github.com/floppydisk525/MvvmLight_WPF_Frame_Nav) and using Win7 and VS2017 Community.  I also have other issues w/ the program and opened issues on github.  Any help is appreciated.

My goal is to have a few basic MVVMLight program 'templates' that I can pull from and share them w/ other learners like me...  Thanks.

### Solution

1. Add Mode=twoway to the binding per @steve-teece.
2. Did some DEBUG.writeline (Break point suggestion per @Michael-Randall) to the output window and found out that the URI for the page was different depending on if it referred back to the viewmodellocater.IntroPageUri or called by the frame FWD or BACK button.

The two URI results were:
/IntroPage.xaml OR IntroPage.xaml

My assumption was that the 'non-fore slash' version didn't equal the version with a '/'.

I'm not sure of the best way to solve this so I converted the URI's to strings and compared them w/ the string Contains method in a boolean method.

I replaced the follow line:

FrameUri != ViewModelLocator.IntroPageUri

It was replaced with a method call:

CheckUri(FrameUri, ViewModelLocator.IntroPageUri)

And, the CheckUri method:

```
    private Boolean CheckUri(Uri _frameUriToCheck, Uri _vmUri)
    {
        string StringUriToCheck = _frameUriToCheck.ToString();
        string StringUriVM = _vmUri.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(StringUriToCheck, "StringUriToCheck");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(StringUriVM, "StringUriVM");

        if (StringUriVM.Contains(StringUriToCheck))
            { return false; }
        else
            { return true; }
    }
```

That worked!  If someone has a better way to solve it, I'm all ears.

Thanks all for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

try changing the XAML to

```
<Frame  x:Name="MainFrameDS"  Source="{Binding FrameUri, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="211" Margin="109,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258"/>
```

Comment: Thought it had really good chance of working.  Tried it and the canexecute didn't update.  One thing that changed was on loading the first IntroPage, the Intro button was disabled, but when I tried Mode=TwoWay, then all the buttons were enabled.  If I used a button, the button then became disabled.  If I used the FWD or BACK button on the frame, all buttons were enabled.  The difference before was that the 'last' button pushed would always stay disabled prior to adding to twoway.  Thanks for the suggestion.  definitely changed the behavior.

Comment: I needed to add the twoway - that helped and was a good catch.

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve Teece, it works nicely !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you are referencing

```
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
```

and not

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
```

If your CanExcute is not getting evaluated you might need to manually raise the change via `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`

```
public Uri FrameUri
{
    get
    {
        return _frameUri;
    }
    set
    {
        if(Set(FrameUriPropertyName, ref _frameUri, value))
        {
            // assuming this is the command you are having trouble with
            // this will force the command to reevaluate CanExecute
            ChangeToLastPage.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Omg i didnt even notice this

```
public const string FrameUriPropertyName = "FrameUri";
```

you need to at least be setting this properly

```
Set(() => FrameUri, ref _frameUri, value);
```

Comment: I definitely have GalaSoft.mvvmlight.CommandWpf;  I did have that problem and when it lacked the Wpf suffix, canexecute didn't really work well at all.  I did try adding the ChangeToLastPage.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); and it didn't change the behavior.  My theory is that the frame BACK & FWD buttons aren't raising the FrameURI property.  Which still makes sense (to me) because we explicitly called out the RaiseCanExecuteChanged methods and they didn't seem to execute.

Comment: I would agree setting the property needs to be done correctly.  When I tried w/ the FrameUri (type URI) I got an error and intellisense asked for a string.  I tried to insert a screen shot into this comment, but can't.  I'll see if I can ad it to your reply.  Thanks - Mark

Comment: @FloppyDisk however, you need to set some break points here, set one on `Set(() => FrameUri, ref _frameUri, value);`, make sure `_frameUri` is being set afterwards, set on one `() => FrameUri != ViewModelLocator.LastPageUri` and let us know the results